# installing redmine_backlog with chiliproject

Tags: ruby, redmine, backlog, chiliproject

I installed chiliproject 3.3.0. After some problems it worked fine...

But now i try to add the BackLog Plugin and i am stucking there...

I did the installation instruction from here: http://www.redminebacklogs.net/en/installation.html
When i call that command `"bundle exec rake redmine:backlogs:install"` i always get that error:

```
root@debian2:~/redmine_backlogs# bundle exec rake redmine:backlogs:install
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:147:in `gem': rake is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
        from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/rake:18
```

I really don't know what to try anymore :S 
Please tell me which information do you need to help me.

Comment: Would be better to ask this on the official forum at http://forum.redminebacklogs.net

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to execute the command in your ChiliProject main directory, e.g. `/path/to/chiliproject`. Any `rake` or `bundle` invocations have to be performed in that main directory, not in the individual plugin directories.